# C++ Error in summing vector

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector

**Task:**

> In a 6x6 array, 16 3x3 array can be constructed. Find the largest sum of the 3x3 array (Source: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-2d-arrays/problem)

Example:

[image]

The largest 3x3 array is

2 4 4

0 2 0

1 2 4

So we print out 19

**My Code:**

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector< vector<int> > arr(6,vector<int>(6));
    for(int arr_i = 0;arr_i < 6;arr_i++){
       for(int arr_j = 0;arr_j < 6;arr_j++){
          cin >> arr[arr_i][arr_j];
       }
    }
    int maxVal = 0;
    for (int y = 2; y < 6; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 2; x < 6; x++)
        {
            if ( y >=2  && x >=2)
            {
                int vert = y;
                int hori = x;
                int first = arr[vert-2][hori] + arr[vert-2][hori-1] + arr[vert-2][hori-2];
                int second = arr[vert-1][hori-1] ;
                int third = arr[vert][hori] + arr[vert][hori-1] + arr[vert][hori-2];
                int sum = first + second + third;
                if (sum > maxVal)
                    maxVal = sum;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << maxVal;
}
```

**Edit:**

I misunderstood the question, but I fixed the problem. Later on, I **still** got incorrect test-cases. The original solution seems to be wrong.

Problem: When I submit the code, some of test case return the wrong answer. I tried reading the code and nothing seems wrong.

Comment: Give us one of the test cases that fails - and the answer it gives. It will be much easier for us to spot the problem then.

Comment: The problem is does it do what it suppose to? The test cases are hidden so you can't predict the input and the output.

Comment: `if ( y >=2  && x >=2)` then why you start your loops with `int y = 0` and `int x = 0`?

Comment: The question in the link is an hourglass one

Comment: You're doing too much at once. You should split your code into simpler functions: one to sum a 3x3 subarray giver its coordinates, and one that loops over the valid coordinates and calls the first function.

Comment: The example happened to have `0` and `0` (hence why the sum is 19), but you need to sum the `hourglass` and not the `3x3`. see my answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem from the provided link is not about the 3x3 submatrices but about the hourglass shapes:

```
a b c
  d
e f g
```

In order to get the correct values; your sum of the second row should be:

```
int second = arr[vert-1][hor-1]
```

And also, there is no need for the if statement as someone already mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaner code. Start from `[1][1]` and iterate till `[length-1][length-1]`. And on each iteration, calculate the sum of the surrounding hourglass.

Also, note that you need to sum the `hourGlass` and NOT the 3x3 subArray.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

    // user input
    //vector< vector<int> > myVector(6,vector<int>(6));
    //for(int arr_i = 0;arr_i < 6;arr_i++)
    //   for(int arr_j = 0;arr_j < 6;arr_j++)
    //       cin >> myVector[arr_i][arr_j];

    // sample input
    vector<vector<int>> myVector = {
                                        { { 1 },{ 1 },{ 1 },{ 0 },{ 0 },{ 0 } },
                                        { { 0 },{ 1 },{ 0 },{ 0 },{ 0 },{ 0 } },
                                        { { 1 },{ 1 },{ 1 },{ 0 },{ 0 },{ 0 } },
                                        { { 0 },{ 0 },{ 2 },{ 4 },{ 4 },{ 0 } },
                                        { { 0 },{ 0 },{ 0 },{ 2 },{ 0 },{ 0 } },
                                        { { 0 },{ 0 },{ 1 },{ 2 },{ 4 },{ 0 } },
                                    };

    int maxVal = -9999; // start with big negative
    for (int y = 1; y < 5; y++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int x = 1; x < 5; x++)
        {
            sum = myVector[y - 1][x - 1] + myVector[y - 1][x] + myVector[y - 1][x + 1]; // first row of the hourglass
            sum += myVector[y][x];                                                      // second row
            sum += myVector[y + 1][x - 1] + myVector[y + 1][x] + myVector[y + 1][x + 1];// third row

            if (sum > maxVal)
                maxVal = sum;
        }
    }
    cout << maxVal << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  int arr[7][7], sum[17], l = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
      cin >> arr[i][j];
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
      sum[l] = 0;
      sum[l] = sum[l] + arr[i][j] + arr[i][j+1] + arr[i][j+2] + arr[i+1][j] + arr[i+1][j+1] + arr[i+1][j+2]+ arr[i+2][j] + arr[i+2][j+1] + arr[i+2][j+2];
      l++;
    }
  }
  sort(sum, sum + 17);
  cout << sum[16];
}
```

## Explanation

This is a simple problem with small values, so we do not need dynamic programming(YAY!).
Vectors are also quite useless here when we can do it correctly with arrays.
Basically I search every set of 3x3 squares, and find the maximum sum.  Hope this helps!